# How to embed Windows Form in unmanaged ATL GUI?

Tags: c++, winforms, atl

I have a Windows form user control that is made COM visible. Now I want to embed that control into an ATL dialog GUI.

The ATL project (unmanaged C++) shall only get the progID of the winform and dynamically create and embed it at runtime.

Is this possible and if so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way to get it to work.
The following code is using a CWnd called m_Control that is made to host a winform via a little documented version of CreateControl. Seems to work fine so far. If anyone sees any drawbacks, please comment or respond.

```
AfxEnableControlContainer();
Microsoft::VisualC::MFC::CControlCreationInfoEx i;
i.Init(System::Type::GetTypeFromProgID(gcnew System::String(sProgID)),
       CControlCreationInfo::ReflectionType);
i.m_clsid = CLSID_WinFormsControl;
POINT pt;
pt.x = pt.y = 0;
SIZE sz;
sz.cx = sz.cy = 100;
m_Control.CreateControl(i, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPCHILDREN,
                        &pt, &sz, CWnd::FromHandle(m_hWnd), ID_CONTROL);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about ATL but this can be done easily in MFC using CWinFormsView and CWinFormsControl classes.

I think there is no bulitin support to host a WinForm Control in an ATL Window but I think you can do it by simple getting the HWND of your winform control and setting your ATL control as its parent. This might be a tough road though.

This seems to be a similar type of thing. I havent tested it myself though.

[Link](http://www.ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2003/01/20/winformshosting.html)

Comment: The approach described in the linked page is not applicable, because it is a winform and not an ActiveX. The latter is not really supported in .Net. When using winforms this way, unexpected things are happening.

Comment: When using CWinFormsControl I have to supply an existing winform class name, because it is a template. However, I want to create an arbitraty winform with a given progID. The actual class is not known at compile time!