# Why can't I enter text in Winform hosted in ATL dialog?

Tags: c++, winforms, atl

I am working on embedding winform controls into an ATL dialog (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642082/how-to-embed-windows-form-in-unmanaged-atl-gui) for how I did so far).

Now I have encountered a rather strange problem.
For some reason, the text fields in my winforms display fine, but I am unable to change the text in them by typing on the keyboard.

However, I can copy and paste text from elsewhere into the text field and it is then treated as normal input (event for text change is fired etc.).

How do I get the text fields to behave normally and allow text input via keyboard?
Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

There's something wrong with your message loop.  TranslateMessage() is the likely candidate, that's the one that generates WM_CHAR messages from a WM_KEYDOWN message.