# Using Windows Form in Win32 applications

Tags: windows, winforms, winapi

I need to create a Win32 application. I am using visual studio. I really like designing my application in Windows Form, which allows graphically designing my window.

However, I cannot use Windows Form (only). I have to use Win32 applicaition. Now, when I create Win32 application, I cannot figure to graphically design my window.

Is there a way to incorporate Windows Form in Win32 application? Or graphically design Win32 window?

(If there is a way to **design** Win32 applications GUI graphically and it's just me who could not figure it, I would appreciate resources or methods to do so.)

Comment: By Win32 and Windows Form, I refer to different modes in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Which type of Win32 project are you trying to create through Visual Studio?

Comment: Saying "Win32 application" do you mean "Console application"?

Comment: @ShaneHaw I don't understand what exactly you mean. There is an option to create "Win32 project" which automatically generated a code that contains _tWinMain and _tWindProc functions. Isn't it a type in itself? . Do you mean CLR/MVC? (I don't quite understand these). I have been programming with pure Win32 API codes directly like using winmain, windproc and then using createwindow,... but that's difficult.

Comment: @user2178841 When you select a new project in Visual Studio it lets you choose which type of project you want to create, for instance on Visual Studio 2012 I select Templates -> Other Languages -> Visual C++ and I have "Win32 Console Application" or "MFC Application" or "Win32 Project", or "Empty Project", or "Makefile Project". What option did you select?

Comment: @ShaneHaw Ah, sorry, I mean I selected "Win32 project".

Comment: @user2178841 Oh ok, what other options did it give you?

Comment: @ShaneHaw, then it pops up a dialog box where to create a file, I chose the location. Then it asks whether to create Console Application, Windows Application, DLL, Static Library. I chose Windows Application. I did not select empty project. And then the the project is created with commands like _tWinMain, _tWndProc,... I don't know how to create window graphically, after this.

Comment: "Win32 Project" is the correct choice if you want to create a graphical Win32 application from Visual Studio. @shane

Comment: @user2178841 I think Cody has the answer that you are looking for.

Comment: My 2 cents: [How to embed Windows Form in unmanaged ATL GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642082/how-to-embed-windows-form-in-unmanaged-atl-gui). You'd need to be familiar with ATL though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a Win32 application, you can include a dialog resource that contains controls and layout information for a particular window. Visual Studio includes a graphical dialog resource editor, as do many other Win32 resource editing applications. This will be somewhat similar to what you're used to with the WinForms designer, albeit with a few limitations. Win32 is a much older technology than WinForms and wasn't really designed with RAD (rapid application development) principles in mind.

When you create a new Win32 project based on the template in Visual Studio, you already get one dialog resource created for you: the About box. If you double-click on your "ProjectName.rc" file in the Solution Explorer, then expand the "Dialog" resources folder, you'll see it. Double-clicking on it will bring up the [Dialog Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6zd672xs.aspx) for this dialog window. You can add controls using the familiar Toolbox window, and customize them using the familiar Properties window.

[image]

You will still need to write code that displays the dialog window, of course. There are two basic methods of doing so:

- The [`DialogBox` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645452.aspx) will display the dialog *modally*, which means that the user has to close the dialog before they can interact with the rest of your application. Inconvenient for the user, but rather convenient for the programmer because Windows runs the dialog's message loop for you.
- The [`CreateDialog` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645434.aspx) will display a normal (non-modal) dialog, but requires that you write your own message loop for the dialog window, just as you would for a normal non-dialog window.

You could conceivably design all of the windows for your application this way, by adding separate dialog resources for each of them, but it is not necessarily a good idea. Part of learning a new UI framework is learning how to use that framework the way it is meant to be used. Creating controls and setting their properties through code at runtime is not really that difficult, and it is a lot more powerful than limiting yourself to a fixed layout. (In fact, even when you have a dialog resource with a fixed layout, you'll often want to write similar code to allow customizing those controls at runtime.)

Comment: Thanks. That's what I had been thinking lately(about managing with dialogues instead). However, I still wanted to know if there is some possibility to incorporate Windows Forms in the Win32 GUIs the way we incorporate Dialogues (or other resources) in Win32 APIs. I definitely do understand the flexibility and power that comes with the possiblity to create/design application during runtime by using Win32.

Comment: @user No, there is not. Not directly, at least. You could create two separate projects, one for the UI in WinForms and the other for the logic targeting Win32 directly, but you'd still need to write some glue that ties them together. It's hard to say whether that would be a good idea without knowing more information about your requirements.